# Mousepad enable button

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, touchpad

I gave windows up, and now installed Ubuntu and am going to move all my work here. I have my first problem now, which is that I have on my laptop (Toshiba Qosmio F750) a button above the touchpad which is supposed to enable/disable it.

On Windows, this button used to work with a driver. Now on linux, I couldn't find a way to get it working. This button is very important for me, because when I'm typing, I tend to touch the touchpad, which could have bad consequences.

My questions:

1- Is it possible to use that button on linux/ubuntu?
2- If not, what's the most efficient way to enable/disable the touchpad quickly?

Thank you for any efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

to turn it off and:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

to turn on.

On my notebook (Toshiba satellite), the button to control the touchpad works in Ubuntu and I don't remember if I had to do something special...